# Add a lot of images dynamically to SQLite Database Android

Tags: android, database, image, sqlite, android-image

I hope you are good.
I'm developping an application that has to retrieve images from sqlite database, for each row  I have one image (using obviously blob as a type), and I was wondering if I could not only add one image but a lot, without knowing how much images the user wants to add, for example: User1 wants to add 3 images to database. User2 5 images and so on. How can I store them? is there a kind of Blob[] or something? And if possible how can I choose more than one image from galery?
I'm not used to make posts in english so I hope I explained well ^^'.
Thank you.

Comment: inserting image into Database is not a good practice. U should place images on file and save the image path to Database is good practice for performance  and image quality

Comment: Yes but I don't really know how I can do it ..... ^^'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the images in a list as base64 strings like:

```
String img1 = Base64.encode(value_of_image, Base64.DEFAULT);
.
.
.
String img25 = Base64.encode(value_of_image, Base64.DEFAULT);

List<String> imagesListActivity = new ArrayList();
imagesList.add(img1);
.
.
.
imagesList.add(img25);
```

and in your save method in helper class, you can do sth like:

```
public void saveImageList(List<String> images){
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    for(int i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
        cv.put(COL_NAME, images[i);
    }
}
```

and in activity class, try this by passing the actual list like below:

```
DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper();
dbHelper.saveImageList(imagesList);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I still have a few questions ... What type is COL_NAME? cause I don't think it's BLOB and I don't know what to put instead, text maybe? cause basically you are storing strings there .... and how can I get the data? I know I have to decode something but how can I get that something for each image? I want to display it after. Thank you so much

Comment: I would recommend you to first learn how to encode and decode base64 strings, any good tutorial will help you with that. Also check this sqlite crud tutorial out - https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-sqlite-database-example/.

Comment: You can also check that of www.androidhive.info, really good content and YES, the COL is of type String. Accept and upvote my answer if it at least points you in the right direction. Thanks.